# Bulk updating ActiveRecord objects in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bulkinsert, bulkupdate

I've got about 60,000 records I want to update. The issue I'm having is that the migration that iterates over them takes too long to run. I'm considering a bulk upsert, but not quite sure how that would look in practice.

Here's what I currently have:

```
Report.find_each(:batch_size => 100) do |rp|
  next if rp.job.blank? || (rp.booked_amount.blank? && rp.approved_estimate.blank?)
  new_declined_est = (rp.booked_amount || 0) - (rp.approved_estimate || 0)
  rp.update_columns(
      booked_amount: rp.job.booked_estimate_amount,
      approved_estimate: rp.job.grand_total,
      declined_estimate: new_declined_est
  )
end
```

^ That's the current task being run as a migration. It takes a long, long time. I've tried this re: bulk upserts (but I'm new to them):

```
Report.find_each(:batch_size => 100) do |rp|
  next if rp.job.blank? || (rp.booked_amount.blank? && rp.approved_estimate.blank?)
  new_declined_est = (rp.booked_amount || 0) - (rp.approved_estimate || 0)
  puts rp
  rp.upsert_all([
                      { booked_amount: rp.job.booked_estimate_amount,
                        approved_estimate: rp.job.grand_total,
                        declined_estimate: new_declined_est },
                  ], unique_by: :id)
end
```

Obviously, I'm doing something wrong here. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: v6.0.3 @dbugger

Comment: Think upsert_all is definitely the way to go.  I'd  be tempted to generate all the update_statements in a batch then call the upsert_all.  What database are you using under the covers?

Comment: @dbugger Using Postgres. What do you mean by generating the update statements in a batch?

Comment: upsert_all takes an array of attributes -- generate an array of things you want updated, then send that array into an upsert_call. Can try doing them all in one go, but you can also do them in batches.

Comment: I see. So in this case, I'm updating certain attributes on the records -- do I need to iterate over them first, or is this handled implicitly by the `upsert_all`?

I'm currently iterating over the records, pushing those records to an array, and then calling `upsert_all`. Is there a better way?

Comment: Should be implicit .  At this point you should be able to see if it works as your desire or if it needs some tweaks.

Comment: @dbugger So how would I access the attributes in the `upsert_all` call similarly to how I'm doing it in the `find_each`?

Comment: @dbugger I used     `Report.upsert_all(Report.map { |rp|
      {booked_amount: rp.job.booked_estimate_amount, approved_estimate: rp.job.grand_total, declined_estimate: (rp.booked_amount || 0) - (rp.approved_estimate || 0)}
    }, unique_by: [:id])` but got `NoMethodError: undefined method `map' for Report (call 'Report.connection' to establish a connection):Class`.

Comment: Not sure why you are mapping there. Also better to update your question with the code.